# Keep reading user keyboard input if available, while echoing back the latest available

Tags: haskell, concurrency, functional-programming, monads

The following code keeps waiting for user input, and echoes it back to screen when it gets it. Then it goes back in waiting-for-input mode. When it's in this state, it keeps writing a constant message on screen.

```hs
import Control.Concurrent
import Data.Maybe
import System.IO

main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  future_input <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ (>>) <$> putMVar future_input
                <*> (putStrLn . ("pressed key: " ++) . return)
                =<< getChar
  wait future_input
    where wait future_input = do
          input <- tryTakeMVar future_input
          if isJust input
            then main
            else putStrLn "keep waiting" >> threadDelay 1000000 >> wait future_input
```

What I would like to obtain, is that the message `keep waiting` be accompained by the *lates available* user input.

The only idea I had so far, is that I should

1. declare another `MVar`, `latest_input` together with `future_input`
2. have the forked thread fill it in at the same time as `future_input`
3. in the `else` of `if isJust input`, I should `tryTakeMVar` from `latest_input` and, if there is something in it (which is, by virtue of point 2, always the case except the first time), I could use it in the output.

However, in this smokey idea of mine, I think I should also have `wait` take both `MVar`s, because I don't have to lose track of any of them when waiting. Similarly, even in the `then` branch of `if isJust input`, I should probably pass `latest_input`, which means I have to use a function other than `main`, which would be called by `main`.

For now, I've got here:

```hs
import Control.Concurrent
import Data.Maybe
import System.IO

main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  future_input <- newEmptyMVar
  latest_input <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ ((>>) .) . (>>)
                <$> putMVar future_input
                <*> putMVar latest_input
                <*> (putStrLn . ("pressed key: " ++) . return)
                =<< getChar
  wait future_input
    where wait future_input = do
          input <- tryTakeMVar future_input
          if isJust input
            then main
            else putStrLn "keep moving" >> threadDelay 1000000 >> wait future_input
```

Comment: By the way, I find those `forkIO $ ...` lines rather hard to read: after two minutes I'm still unsure about how to parse them. If you prefer that style, that's alright, but note that you can write `forkIO $ do ...` and start a new `do` block, as long as you indent it more than the outer block.

Comment: @chi I think maybe the `((>>) .) . (>>)` is indeed hard to read. It's probably more readable if written as `\x y z -> x >> y >> z`), but writing it this more explicit way should make what the following four lines do. I am, however, forcing myself to avoid `do` whenever it's not too hard, in an attempt to get a better understanding of monads and applicatives.

Comment: I see, but I finally figured out you are using _three_ different monads there! Namely, `[]` for `return`, `IO` for `(>>)`, and `(->) Char` for `<$>, <*>`. The indentation also does not suggest the parsing `( (>>) <$> ... <*> ...) =<< getChar`, IMO. Anyway, forgive me for these comments of mine which are irrelevant to the actual question.

Comment: @chi yes, there are 3 monads there. If you can suggest a better indenting, that'd be good :) You can edit my question directly, if you like,as it's probably easier and quicker than explaining where  spaces should be put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, I think I got it :D (and I've put it in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249322/keep-reading-user-keyboard-input-if-available-while-echoing-back-the-latest-ava)).

```hs
import Control.Concurrent
import Data.Maybe
import System.IO

main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  future_input <- newEmptyMVar
  latest_input <- newEmptyMVar
  putMVar latest_input 'A' -- assuming a previous input the first time
  work future_input latest_input

work :: MVar Char -> MVar Char -> IO ()
work future_input latest_input = do
  forkIO $ ((>>) .) . (>>)
                <$> putMVar future_input
                <*> tryPutMVar latest_input
                <*> (putStrLn . ("pressed key: " ++) . return)
                =<< getChar
  wait future_input latest_input
    where wait future_input latest_input = do
          input <- tryTakeMVar future_input
          old_input <- takeMVar latest_input
          if isJust input
            then do
              putMVar latest_input (fromJust input)
              work future_input latest_input
            else do
              putMVar latest_input old_input
              putStrLn ("latest input was " ++ (return old_input))
                >> threadDelay 1000000
                >> wait future_input latest_input
```